# jQuery Validation Plugin and asynchronous updates

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, validation

I have the script shown below, and also duplicated at http://jsbin.com/vuliw/1.

The input `#address` is validated to be (4) or more characters, and will also autopopulate given a couple of characters.

My problem is it is validated before the input is populated.  To replicate, enter a couple of characters (less than 4), and click one of the results.  While my example uses the Google Maps API, I expect I will get these results with any asynchronous update.

How can I validate minimum length?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Validation</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                address.value='';
                var validator=$("#myForm").validate({rules: {address: {"minlength": 4,"required":true}}});
                var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('address'));
            });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="myForm" action="bla.php" method="post">
            <input id="address" name="address" type="text">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            address.value='';
            var validator=$("#myForm").validate({rules: {address: {"minlength": 4,"required":true}}});
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('address'));
            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function(){
                $("#myForm").valid();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Re-run your validation after a user selects an item.  You can do so with the valid() method, cued by the `place_changed` autocomplete event.

Comment: Thanks John,  Appears to work, but am still testing.  Can you explain how this allows it to work?

Comment: Since things are asynchronous, you need to make sure that your check happens after Google has done its work. G fires an event (place_changed) to tell you so, which is cued off of a user selection from the autocomplete list. So, if we just make sure to run our checks every time after G is finished, it won't interfere with anything else.  At worst, you're running an extra unnecessary check, but that is due to how the validate() plugin listens to events. It would require you to make core changes inside of that library to remove an ms or two of extra checks IFF a user selects an autocomplete item.

Comment: Ah, I understand.  The validation plugin first validates the given element and displays an error, then Google does it thing, then the entire form is validated but this time the given element no longer shows an error.  Any other elements on the form, however, will be validated before the user needs to see the errors.  Could just the one element be validated using something like `$("#myForm").valid("address");`?  I tried but no luck.

Comment: `$('#address').valid()` will check the field without validating the entire form.

Comment: Implemented John's solution along with Jeffery's comment.  http://jsbin.com/vuliw/8/.  Seems reasonable, and definitely better than re-writing the validation plugin.